# Rating system for bbPress

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I am looking for a rating/voting system for bbPress. Comments or Topics that are rated high, should appear higher.

If this isn't possible, is there a forum, in Wordpress or Rails, that supports anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

check this here u can find [plugins for Quotes, Ratings and Unread Posts](http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/introducing-plugins-for-quotes-ratings-and-unread-posts/)